# Black hole interior

Tags: black-holes, entropy, event-horizon, singularities

Had a few questions about the "interior" of the black hole.

I've read that all the mass of a black hole is concentrated at it's center and that you can't isolate an object to an area of space smaller than its Compton Wavelength. Is there any semi-classical way to address this issue without Loop quantum Gravity or String Theory?

The Event Horizon behavior contributed by the black hole is due to mass at the center, possibly far away, say L light years. Suppose some mass distribution a small fraction L light years from the event horizon is manipulated whether by natural or artificial interactions. Suppose there is some detector near the mass distribution. Will that detector measure a response from the black hole significantly sooner than L years? I'd expect the response to take longer if the response manipulates mass at the center than at the surface.

Comment: In the last paragraph, are you talking about a black hole with a radius of 20 light-years? FWIW, the largest black hole candidate yet detected, in the quasar TON 618, may be as large as 66 billion solar masses, which would give it a Schwarzschild radius of about 0.02 light-years.

Comment: @PM2Ring. Yep. Thanks for the info. My main concern is the physics of closer proximity to the event horizon than the center of mass of the black hole.

Comment: This could be split into 2-3 questions.